# Xampp PHP write JSON file permission

Tags: php, html, apache

I have some problems with Xampp in Windows 10. I have changed the Document Root folder in my dropbox folder (www). I can`t create json files using PHP.

I have a PHP script file:

```
...
$json = json_encode($files, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
if (file_put_contents("../myJson.json", $json))
    echo "JSON updated successfully...";
else 
    echo "Oops! Error updating json file...";
```

And tells me that "echo "Oops! Error updating json file...";"

I have check the file with is_writable function and it is.

I changed the root web folder permission to Everyone (Full Access) and the same error.

In Linux it`s working fine, but not in Windows 10

I know that is a permission setting wrong but i dont know where.

Comment: Give write permission to your script/user that runs it.

Comment: i gave it but not working

Comment: Same as _always_ with php errors: what does your http servers error log file say? You simply _cannot_ programm on php in a web environment without monitoring that file. That is like flying blind in a dark cave.

Comment: Here is it the file with error from xampp
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1378870/error.log

Comment: The modification i made in httpd.conf are:
i replaced the C:/xampp/htdocs with my new dir and this:
<Directory "C:/Users/Calin/Dropbox/www">
 Options All
     AllowOverride All
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
</Directory>